# ExpressionEngine show channel content outside of loop

Tags: expressionengine

I know this sounds crazy, but I need to show some post information outside of the loop in the expression engine channel module. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use EE's SQL Query template tags (if you know, or have access to the database table names and know what to look for in the database):

http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/query/index.html

Basically, you'd output only what you need - it doesn't have to belong to a channel, or anything specific. The one kicker is that you'd have to know the basics of SQL syntax, but if you have a small working knowledge of it, you can do tons of additional things with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not keen on SQL, you could simply embed a template within the template that you're working on. Here's a simple example that assumes you're editing the `index` and `meta` templates inside of a template group called `'news'`:

`index` template contents:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
  <div class="entry">
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <div class="content">{body}</div>
    {embed="news/meta" this_entry_id="{entry_id}"}
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

---

`meta` template contents:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" limit="1" entry_id="{embed:this_entry_id}"}
  <div class="meta">
    <p>{entry_date}</p>
    <p>{author}</p>
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

As you can see, the `index` template is embedding the `meta` template. Note that we're passing a parameter to the `meta` template so that it knows which entry ID to print information about. If you're unfamiliar with EE's template embedding feature, you can read more about it in the [EE docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding_templates.html). Embedding templates in other templates is a great way to access the `{exp:channel:entries}` loop multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

There's an add-on called MX Jumper that allows you to "set" a variable from inside your entries loop and then "get" it elsewhere in the template (before or after in the HTML loop doesn't matter because it parses later).

Alternatively, the approach that's all the rage now is to use the add-on Stash to store any and all elements you need to use distinctly as stash variables that you set and then get - similar to the above, except that once you set them, getting them has to happen at a later parsing stage.  The beauty of this approach is stash will store the "set" variables for reuse either at a user or site level, and you can determine what the expiry period is - which then results in better performance. When you apply this broadly using the "template partials" mindset, you can store everything with stash, and then call them into a small number of wrapper templates.  This makes it possible to use stash to set, for example, your entry title, then get it three separate times in the wrapper template without any additional load - no need for separate loops within your template - one loop to set the variable, and then you can call that variable as needed in your template - it's kind of like creating global variables on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest looking at [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash).